# python parsing url after string

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I want to extract a string from a url (link). That string is in a `<h3></h3>` tag.

```
 link = http://www.test.com/page.html

 Content of link: <h3>Text here</h3>
```

What would be an elegant way to first get the content/sourcecode of page.html and then exctract the link?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib2
url="http://www.test.com/page.html"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
data=page.read()
for item in data.split("</h3>"):
    if "<h3>" in item:
         print item.split("<h3>")[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [Beatiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). That's a nice parser for botched HTML pages (for the most cases you don't have to worry about the page not being well-formed).

Answer (score 1):

You can use URLLib2 to retrieve the content of the URL:

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

You could then use the HTML parser in the Python libraries to find the right content:

http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html

Answer (score -1):

Provided the text you want is the *only* `<h3>`-wrapped text on the page, try:

`from urllib2 import urlopen`
`from re import search`
`text = search(r'(?<=<h3>).+?(?=</h3>)', urlopen(link).read()).group(0)`

If there are multiple `<h3>`-wrapped strings you can either put more details into the pattern or use `re.finditer()`/`re.findall()`

Comment: You should use a non-greedy qualifier as otherwise it may match something like 'Heading</h3>........<h3>Other Heading'

Comment: OP's task is just to get <h3> tags, using regex is perfectly ok.